# How can i sort the bins within bin ranges?

Tags: sorting

i have following bins and binranges:

```
ages = {3, 12, 24, 15, 5, 74, 23, 54, 31, 23, 64, 75};
binranges = {0, 10, 25, 50, 75};
PositionIndex[BinLists[ages, {binranges}]
```

will give me indices of bins within binranges. how can i relate these indices to ages so it would be [ 1     2     2     2     1     4     2     4     3     2     4] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bl = BinLists[ages, {binranges}];
Flatten@Most[Pick[Range@Length@bl, 
     Function[{x}, Intersection[x, {#}] === {#}] /@ bl] & /@ ages]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4}

Also

```
Flatten[Position[bl, {___,#,___}]&/@ages]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4}